# “Failed to join server: The workspace has local changes.”

Tags: game-development, unreal-engine5

We (Multi-user editing) were casually editing the game when it crashed so we all had to exit, but when entering back. An error popped up stating that “Failed to join server: The workspace has local changes.” So then I searched up the error and found this solution in the bottom. We tried it but didn’t work

In order to maintain the same state across all users, Multi-User Editing requires that all users have the same starting state. You are receiving this error message because you have changes to the project in source control that have yet to be committed. In order to join, you must revert these changes or submit them and have the other users sync to the new changelist.

I tried the solution that the document recommended but after all of those tries, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried what it asks? `you have changes to the project in source control that have yet to be committed. In order to join, you must revert these changes or submit them and have the other users sync to the new changelist`

Comment: Yes, multiple times